# How can you know if a stream is closed?

Tags: c#, .net, stream

I have a method with a Stream for input :

```
public void Export(Stream finalOutPutStream)
```

For test purposes, i call it with a memory stream, like this :

```
// When
_exporter.Export(new System.IO.MemoryStream());
```

But when, in the method, i want to write on this memory stream, i get a ObjectDisposedException.

This stream is not enclosed in a using statement, i do not call explicitely .Dispose().

What happened ?

Thanks :)

--
EDIT : my bad, the problem is from the third party writer ([DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)). The exception happens when i call zip.Save(new MemoryStream()). I will ask my questions on their forum.
Sorry, and thanks for the help.

Comment: How do you write to the stream? If, for example, you wrap your `finalOutPutStream` in a `StreamWriter`, closing the `StreamWriter` will also close the underlying stream.

Comment: the exception happens at the moment i write, before the stream writer is closed. But thanks, i did not know that the underlying stream would be closed too !

Comment: You get exception inside `Export` method?

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you post an example of how you write to the stream? Also, are you sure that you are not creating a `StreamWriter`, disposing it, and then creating a new one? The second one will be in an invalid state, as the underlying stream will be disposed.

Comment: yeah, exactly when i want to write on the memorystream.

Comment: please show the code of `Export` method...

Comment: `bool IsAlive(StreamReader streamReader) { try { return !streamReader.EndOfStream; } catch {return false;}} `

Comment: If you don't have any idea why the stream is being closed I would wrap in a try catch and handle it from there.

Answer (score 13):

You can check stream availability using: `CanRead`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite` properties.

Comment: I'm working on figuring this out as well. I'm handing the stream to another class. While it is true that nothing else should attempt to arbitrarily use the stream, its kind of difficult to unit test the functionality of ordering the stream closed and then have all those properties return true. :/

Comment: CanRead  of  stream from closed Process always returns  True

Comment: This doesn't works.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (and verified in my testing) that those properties are just saying that this type of stream supports reading/writing/etc. It doesn't seem like they update if the stream is closed. Technically, we can still read from the stream when it's closed, we just won't get anything back.

Comment: from the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.canread?view=net-7.0

If the stream is closed, this property returns false.

so it should work yes if you know that your stream type would otherwise be able to read

Comment: Test 7.2023: I close stream so CanRead = false. I think docs of microsoft exactly.